# XSL: Set Table Column Fix width

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a xsl file which makes a table of some columns.
If the content of the data to be written is too long then the column width increases and surpasses the right boundary of the screen.
For instance in below script if the value of key "Name" is too long then cell will be too wide.

How can I fix the width of each of the column upto certain width so that I add any no. of columns and all are of fixed/same width and lies within the screen?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>test result</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
            </head>

            <body id="body">
                <xsl:for-each select="/test_result">                
                            <table">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                            <xsl:call-template name="new_test" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="new_test">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Name: Test1
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
            Result: Pass
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Name: Test2_123456790_123456790_123456790_123456790_123456790_123456790_123456790_123456790_123456790_123456790_123456790_123456790
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
            Result: Fail
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: You can do this with the HTML `width="xxx"`  attribute on the `<td>` elements.

Comment: Thanks zx485 for the hint. Can you provide any link for reference?

Comment: Try [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_width.asp). The `width` attribute can be applied to `tr` and `td` elements as well. Or look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_td.asp): "How to set the width of a table cell (with CSS)" - `<td style="width:70%">January</td>`.

Comment: I tried using         <td width="10%">. But this does not help.

Comment: We cannot help you further without a [mcve]. Please create one for this question or a new one.